# How to get Video Thumbnail from Uint8List in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

The app I am working on allows users to create social posts like Facebook with text, images and videos. I am working on PWA part and I came across this issue. For selecting video from storage, I need to create a thumbnail of the video to display in UI.

I was able to pick video as `Uint8List` as it is supported in all the platforms but I couldn't get a thumbnail from it. I tried many libraries but all are using `File` as an input.

Is there any way I can get this done?

I am using following code to get Uint8List of video File...

Library used: [file_picker_cross](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker_cross)

```dart
final filePicker = FilePickerCross(type: FileTypeCross.video);
await filePicker.pick();
final imageBytes = filePicker.toUint8List();
// TODO: get video thumbnail from [imageBytes]
```

Comment: I know it does but the question is how can I get a thumbnail out of a video `Uint8List`?

Comment: wait wait wait, you have the binary content of the whole video? like 1GB for 2 hour cinema movie?

Comment: Not like that actually. See I am trying to combine android/ios app with pwa. As `File` class comes from different packages on both platforms, I am left with `Uint8List`. So I am trying to make it work and get a thumbnail from it. This solution only seems viable to be and I haven't tried to actually load video as `Uint8List` if that's what you're asking. The app doesn't allow uploading of videos more than 15 MB I guess.

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/video_thumbnail/latest/

Comment: @pskink I came across this package but as it didn't support loading thumbnail from `Uint8List`, I didn't give it a try! Iet me do that now with File! Thanks.

Comment: you need a `String` file path, not `Uint8List` - see https://pub.dev/documentation/file_picker/latest/file_picker/FilePicker/getFilePath.html

Comment: `file_picker` doesn't work for web...

Comment: Unfortunately, no!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check out this package (works on web also ) : it's plugin generates thumbnail from video file or URL : **[get_thumbnail_video](https://pub.dev/packages/get_thumbnail_video)**
2. Use an external services or APIs designed for video processing, that can accept video URLs or video files as inputs and return generated thumbnails. To implement this, your Flutter web app would make HTTP requests to these services, and they'd return the thumbnail image.
3. Implement Server-Side Processing : for this you can use Node.js, Python, or any backend framework. The server can handle video thumbnail generation since you have more control over server-side libraries like FFmpeg or OpenCV.
4. Leverage JavaScript Libraries : using flutter web, you have the ability to communicate with JavaScript using the `dart:js` package. This opens up the option to utilize JavaScript libraries like `video.js` or `flv.js` for showing videos and extracting thumbnails. This essentially means you're creating a connection between your Dart code and JavaScript to handle more advanced video-related tasks. ( I think you can find more here : **[Render video thumbnails using HTML canvas](https://medium.com/@c.nwaugha/render-video-thumbnails-using-html-canvas-dc7d08a5ed6f)** )

this is just an example in code of capturing a video frame as a thumbnail using JavaScript and the `HTML5` `canvas` element :

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js' as js;

void captureThumbnail(VideoElement videoElement) {
  CanvasElement canvas = CanvasElement(width: videoElement.videoWidth, height: videoElement.videoHeight);
  var context = canvas.context2D;
  context.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0);
  Blob thumbnailBlob = canvas.toBlob('image/jpeg', 0.7);
}
// then you can work with the thumbnailBlob
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Wow...This package added support for it 2 months ago! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you got check the packages (versions & supported platforms), flutter web usually missing some packages that only exist for mobile... so you have to find your way around that. I also recommend you check here (https://fluttergems.dev/video/).

Answer (score -1):

U might use video_thumbnail 0.2.5+1 plugin in your flutter project

```
final uint8list = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
 video: videofile.path,
 imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
 maxWidth: 128,
// specify the width of the thumbnail, let the height auto-scaled to keep the source aspect ratio
quality: 25,
);
```

);

Comment: I used this and it worked for mobile. But it didn't work on web.

Comment: @BirjuVachhani were you ever able to create a thumbnail for a video on flutter web?

Comment: Nope. I did not.

Comment: did you find any thing ?

Comment: any soultion on this?

Comment: any solution for this

Comment: Nope, I did not.